# stackdriver not monitoring kafka metrics

Tags: monitoring, google-cloud-platform, kafka, google-stackdriver

I am trying to setup kafka metrics on stackdriver. I followed all steps as mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/kafka , but still cant see "kafka" metrics. Although I can see metrics of Host, Agent, Zookeeper and JVM

I can also see the metrics from kafka's script: `bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.JmxTool --object-name 'kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec' --jmx-url service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:9
999/jmxrmi`

Result of above script: `"time","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:Count","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:EventType","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:FifteenMin
uteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:FiveMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:MeanRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:
OneMinuteRate","kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec:RateUnit"
1546947405966,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS
1546947407959,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS
1546947409963,0,messages,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,SECONDS`

Comment: After making sure that monitoring [agent is installed](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#linux-install), check your agent version with `dpkg -l stackdriver-agent` as it requires version 5.5.0-257 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Check the custom metrics tab in the stackdriver, The Kafka metrics are loaded in there